# How to override a function in another javascript file?

Tags: javascript, overriding

I have a JavaScript file, `Mybasefile.js`, which has the function `Mybasefunction()`. I want to override this function in another JavaScript file. When the function is called in a button click, I want the original `Mybasefunction()` to be executed along with some other code. How can I do this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

place this code in the override file. Make sure the override file is included after the orginal one.

```
var orig_Mybasefunction = window.Mybasefunction;
window.Mybasefunction = function(){
    orig_Mybasefunction();
    ...
}
```

Comment: +1 this should work - @Jis see the edit, it should fix the problem.

Comment: You might want to hide the `orig_Mybasefunction` variable by wrapping this code in an anonymous function: `(function () { var orig_ ... }());`

That way, you won't clobber the global namespace, and you'll be able to use the name `orig_Mybasefunction` elsewhere without disturbing this code.

Comment: I know, I know -- but let's get the basics down first.